# Client ack for server-emitted events in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

We use this code to emit events on node.js/socket.io server:

```
socketio.sockets.in(room).emit('event', data);
```

Is it possible for the server to receive a confirmation from the clients?

I know this is possible and common the other way around, i.e., emit an event from client, and get the confirmation from the server. But I can't find any topic on the scenario mentioned above.

If it's not possible, how can I detect server-emitted event delivery errors?